# AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'strip'", 'occurred at index DIV') in Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to strip the spaces across my pandas data frame .
I am using the following code for my data frame d1 .

cols = df1.select_dtypes(object).columns
df1[cols] = df1[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())

**But Getting the follwoing error:**

df1[cols] = df1[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'strip'", 'occurred at index DIV') .

How to get rid of this ?

Comment: check with null value, your column might contain null value

Comment: @GyanaranjanNayak it's up to you how you want to handle missing values. You could replace them with empty strings using df.fillna or drop the row from the dataframe using df.dropna. (both these methods can be applied to individual columns as well as a whole dataframe).